# Why google tag manager event is not being reflected in GA 4 report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics, google-analytics-4, web-analytics-tools

I have configured a GA 4 custom event in GTM via tag but I can't see that event firing anywhere in realtime report or anywhere else except in debug timeline of GA 4 console and in tag assistant of GTM.

As you can see in below screenshot of tag assistant , My custom event for GA4 is "checkout_confirm" which is being configured via  checkout_confirm tag which is firing
once checkout is being done and seems working fine with params as intended

In analytics dashboard when I go and try to find that event data (even after 24 hours), It shows nothing but it is showing fired when I go to debug view of GA4 as you can see in second screenshot

Also in screenshot 3 as shown , google analytics debugger extension in browser console is showing that Google analytics is collecting data.

Please guide me , where am I missing , I am stucked from days . Kindly help me.

[image: As you can see in below screenshot of tag assistant , My custom event for GA4 is "checkout_confirm" which is being configured via checkout_confirm tag which is firing once checkout is being done and seems working fine with params as intended]

[image: In analytics dashboard when I go and try to find that event data (even after 24 hours), It shows nothing but it is showing fired when I go to debug view of GA4 as you can see in second screenshot)]

[image: Also in screenshot 3 as shown , google analytics debugger extension in browser console is showing that Google analytics is collecting data.]

Comment: Did you know what happened & the solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Events uploaded in Debug Mode are filtered out from standard reports. See "Also, data captured while Debug Mode is running will be filtered out of your other reports so that it does not artificially inflate your metrics (in other words, no more separate GA properties for production and staging)." from [Validating Google Analytics 4 with Debug Mode](https://ken-williams.com/guide/installation/validating-google-analytics-4-with-debug-mode/).

You'll need to remove the parameters like `_dbg=1` that is labeling this event as debug, and then, this `checkout_confirm` will show up in realtime and `checkout_confirm`'s event-detail reports.

Comment: I don't think that was the question. From my understanding and from looking at my own problem with GA4, I believe he was able to see his events in the debug mode but when triggered through a user on the website they would not show up in the GA panel. That's at least what I encountered myself

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is you're probably using a browser that blocks trackers (such as Brave or Tor) when you use the website outside the debug mode. Is that the case?

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me: One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.